# Interpolate 2d numpy array to change shape

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I've a numpy array of shape `(960, 2652)`, I want to change its size to `(1000, 1600)` using linear/cubic interpolation.

```
>>> print(arr.shape)
(960, 2652)
```

I've check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38065352/6210807) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33261924/6210807) answer, which recommends to use [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html), but what should I provide as `x` and `y`?

```
from scipy import interpolate
f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, arr, kind='cubic')
```

Comment: X and y can be range objects as coordinates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The datapoints on the old domain, i.e.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = misc.face(gray=True)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, arr.shape[0])
y = np.linspace(0, 1, arr.shape[1])
f = interpolate.interp2d(y, x, arr, kind='cubic')

x2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
y2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 1600)
arr2 = f(y2, x2)

arr.shape # (768, 1024)
arr2.shape # (1000, 1600)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(arr)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(arr2)
```

Answer (score 2):

[skimage.transform.resize](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize) is a very convenient way to do this:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import resize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import misc
    
arr = misc.face(gray=True)

dim1, dim2 = 1000, 1600
    
arr2= resize(arr,(dim1,dim2),order=3)  #order = 3 for cubic spline
    
print(arr2.shape) 

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(arr)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**for new version of spicy (>1.10)**

```
import numpy as np
import spipy as sp

def inter_image(image, size_out):    
    x_size = image.shape[0]
    y_size = image.shape[1]

    x = np.linspace(0, 1, x_size)
    y = np.linspace(0, 1, y_size)
    f = sp.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator((y, x), image)

    x = np.linspace(0, 1, size_out[0])
    y = np.linspace(0, 1, size_out[1])
    xg, yg = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    return  f((yg, xg))
```