# How to make a graph with x and y of different length

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, interpolation

I'm trying to make a Python app that shows a graph after the input of the data by the user, but the problem is that the `y_array` and the `x_array` do not have the same dimensions. When I run the program, this error is raised:

`ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes () and ()`

How can I draw a graph with the X and Y axis of different length?

Here is a minimal example code that will lead to the same error I got
:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [0, 8, 9, 3, 0]
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's good that you have your code available, but it'd make the job of answering your question faster and easier if you provided a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, type up a test plot with the two arrays of differing size and reproduce your error with this. If it is as simple as making differing array sizes to match, there is an answer for interpolation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064697/interpolating-a-numpy-array-to-fit-another-array)

Comment: I'm sorry. Thanks for the advice, I have modified the question with a more legible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is virtually a copy/paste of the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064697/interpolating-a-numpy-array-to-fit-another-array), but I'll show what I did to get these to match.

First, we need to decide which array to use- the `x_array` of length 7, or the `y_array` of length 5. I'll show both, starting with the former. Note that I am using `numpy` arrays, not lists.

Let's load the modules

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as interp
```

and the arrays

```
y = np.array([0, 8, 9, 3, 0])
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

In both cases, we use `interp.interp1d` which is described in detail in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html).

For the `x_array` to be reduced to the length of the `y_array`:

```
x_inter = interp.interp1d(np.arange(x.size), x)
x_ = x_inter(np.linspace(0,x.size-1,y.size))

print(len(x_), len(y))
# Prints 5,5

plt.plot(x_,y)
plt.show()
```

Which gives

[image: x_array]

and for the `y_array` to be increased to the length of the `x_array`:

```
y_inter = interp.interp1d(np.arange(y.size), y)
y_ = y_inter(np.linspace(0,y.size-1,x.size))

print(len(x), len(y_))
# Prints 7,7
plt.plot(x,y_)
plt.show()
```

Which gives

[image: y_array]